# How to find locations (Lat, Long) within a distance from my user position (Lat, Long) with solr?

Tags: solr, geospatial

I've a list of store coordinates (Lat, Long) with a given radius of visibility. I also have a user position (Lat, Long). I want to search for all store coordinates for which the user position is within the store visibility. The problem needs to be solved with Solr.

Currently I'm generating circles as polygons around the store coordinates. If the user position is within the polygon, I return the store coordinate. This approach works but the indexing of the polygons is too slow (200k Polygons -> 40 Minutes).

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in other terms (correct me if I'm wrong), you want to retrieve each store for which the visibility radius is greater than or equal to the distance between the store location and the user location.

That means excluding all stores that are not in a "visible area" around the *user* (since distance *from A to B* is interchangeable with distance *from B to A*).

In fact the catch (if I'm not completely wrong) is that the radius *depends* on the store that the user is querying so you may have to do some parameter substitution and use [geofilt](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/spatial-search.html#geofilt) as a filter query with a variable distance.

Here an example using arbitrary user coordinates `pt=45.91,6.13` and the [`field()`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html#FunctionQueries-AvailableFunctions) [function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html#FunctionQueries-AvailableFunctions) to retrieve the value of the store radius :

```
fq={!geofilt sfield=store_coord pt=45.91,6.13 d=field(store_visibility)}
```

..assuming you have `store_coord` or equivalent defined as a LatLonPointSpatialField (or location) and `store_visibility` defined as an integer.

Add `fl=geodist()` to your query to check the actual distance from the user to every matched store location, as computed by {!geofilt}.

Similarly you can sort by distance : `sort=geodist()+asc`